# Check if Node(instance of Class) is Clicked

Tags: java, processing

Hey I am working on a small project in the aim to accelerate my learning and have come into a problem , I have an arraylist of class instances each with and x,y location and each have been mapped to fit inside a window , and am wondering how I may go about implementing functionality which would allow user to click on a node( an ellipse on screen at the mapped x,y value from a instance of class) and for my program to somehow have a toggle to display information about this node in another part of the screen , I have looked for code examples and havent found one that I can get working with my senario here is my class

```
class Ship{
    float yPos;
    float xPos;

    Ship(String line){
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        xPos = float(parts[4]);
        yPos = float(parts[5]);
    }
}
```

I am taking in data from a csv file and splitting it etc,
I have alot of code so if my example isnt enough I will add specific parts if needed,
Thanks in advance , 
Kind Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Your code didn't show your implementation, it's just data sets now. Please be more detailed and provide your implementation. Also, I'd suggest you to make your `float yPos` and `float xPos` as `private`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add logic for detecting whether the mouse is inside the object.

Exactly how you do this depends on how your object is shaped.

- If your object is a circle, you can simply use the `dist()` function to check whether the mouse is inside the circle.
- If your object is a rectangle, then you just have to check whether the cursor position is inside that rectangle. Draw out a few examples on a piece of paper to help figure this out.
- If your object is in a grid, then you can map the cursor position to a grid position.
- If your object is more complicated, like a polygon, then your logic will have to be more complicated. Google is your friend with this one.

In any case, you're going to have to try something, put together an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (note: this should not be  your whole sketch, it should be a small example that we can copy and paste to run ourselves) and ask a more specific question. Good luck.